# What's the shortest generating one-way hash algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, hashing

I have a 24 character long id which is guaranteed to be unique. I would like to shorten that to 7-10 (or even shorter) characters long. If I generate an short id randomly then I would have to check every time if that shortid is available. Is there an one-way hash algorithm that could return back 7-10 character hash from passing in the 24 character id.

Are there any other ways to guarantee that the generated short id is unique without checking?

Comment: "24 character long id" - what characters are in this character set?  You might be able to shorten it just by re-encoding it in something that allows for a larger character set.

Comment: 0-9,a-z no uppercases or symbols.

Comment: Then you can cut it down to half its size by adding in symbols (shifted number) and upper case.

Comment: I think most people would be smart enough to realize you cannot hash a big set into a small set without having collision, so can I ask that: do you have a guarantee that the cardinality of the set of 24-char ids is less than the number of possible combinations one can make from 7-10 char Id?

Comment: **TL;DR** It can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* guarantee that a shortened ID is unique, because there are much fewer 10-character strings than 24-character strings. Sooner or later, values **will** be reused.

Depending on how your IDs are generated, there are different things you could do in practice. If you get consecutive numbers, taking their last 10 characters will work for a while, but then wrap around after X^10 values. If the ID is itself totally random, you can take any 10 of its digits to get another value that is *probably* unique, but sooner or later will lead to collisions unpredictably. But the problem as posed is not solvable.

Comment: What's the shortest id I could get if not 7-10? Which hashing algorithm can I use?

Comment: The shortest ID is 24 characters. Any shorter than that and it *cannot possibly* be unique per the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Sorry I haven't made myself clear enough. Hashing can try to distribute the inevitable collisions evenly, but it cannot prevent them. If you really do need guaranteed unique IDs, you **must** require that restriction in the step where you generate IDs, e.g. reprogram the ID generator to use only 10 characters in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If other conditions are favorable, assign your short ids serially.  First string
that needs an Id gets 1, second get 2 etc.  Guaranteed to be unique and no checking
is needed.